# Identity Server still including in-memory keys in discovery doc after providing custom implementation of ISigningCredentialStore

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I'm working on an app that uses the [IdentityServer6 library](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer). Out of the box this seems to use a pair of in-memory signing keys which I can see in the jwks discovery doc when run locally.

I've now provided a custom implementation of `ISigningCredentialStore` and `IValidationKeysStore` to load my own key pair from an external source. These I've registered as [per the docs](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/crypto.html) like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISigningCredentialStore, MySigningCredentialStore>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IValidationKeysStore, MyValidationKeysStore>();
```

However, when I run this I now get the original pair of keys, **plus** my own two in the discovery doc, so four in total. So how can I stop IdentityServer using its own keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I worked this out. Needed to set `KeyManagement.Enabled` to `false` in the options for `AddIdentityServer`.